# Rotate a rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to rotate a rectangle when mouse is moving. 
**My code:**

```
private int i = 0;

private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    RotateTransform rotation = new RotateTransform();
    rotation.Angle = i;
    rotation.CenterX = Canvas.GetLeft(rect) + rect.Width/2;
    rotation.CenterY = Canvas.GetTop(rect) + rect.Height/2;
    rect.LayoutTransform = rotation;
    i++;         
}
```

I want to make rotation by center of my rectangle, but it making it in another way. This lines:

```
rotation.CenterX = Canvas.GetLeft(rect) + rect.Width/2;
rotation.CenterY = Canvas.GetTop(rect) + rect.Height/2;
```

dont change anything at all. Do you know why ?

I found a solution in another post in this forum, so my **solution** for this is:

```
            double left = Canvas.GetLeft(rect);
            double top = Canvas.GetTop(rect);

            Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 0);
            Canvas.SetTop(rect, 0);

            RotateTransform rotation = new RotateTransform();
            rotation.Angle = i;
            rotation.CenterX = rect.Width/2;
            rotation.CenterY = rect.Height/2;
            rect.RenderTransform = rotation;

            Canvas.SetLeft(rect, left);
            Canvas.SetTop(rect, top);
            i++;
```

Comment: Well, on the face of it I'd say you're not setting an angle (`i` is always `0`), and you're setting the centre value to the centre of rectangle. So I'm not surprised nothing is happening. (You've essentially applied a transformation that does nothing)

Comment: No, it does rotate my rectangle i is incremented every time when mouse position is changed, so it rotate my rectangle, but it rotate it like in the first picture: [image](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC1813.gif), and i want it to make like in second picture.

Comment: What does the debugger state for the values of `Canvas.GetLeft(rect)` and `rect.Width`?

Comment: @Chris Sinclair Debuger dont says anything, this code works fine, but i want another kind of ratation :P

Comment: I'm suggesting that the values that you're using to apply the rotation to the centre of the object are incorrect.

Comment: @Chris Sinclair, can you help me find rectangle center then? I tryied rect.RadiusX, rect.RadiusY as well but it seems to be not working.

Comment: _What does the debugger state for the values of `Canvas.GetLeft(rect)` and `rect.Width`?_

Comment: I draw a small rectangle inside my main rectangle: [image](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/6967/przechwytywanieac.jpg) It seems to be center is found good.

Answer (score 6):

I guess what you actually want is a [RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) with a [RenderTransformOrigin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin.aspx) at the center of the Rectangle:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Orange" Width="100" Height="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform"/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

Write the MouseMove handler like this:

```
double angle = 0;

private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    rotateTransform.Angle = angle; // yes, Angle is a double
    angle += 1;
}
```

Comment: And by the way, your approach should omit the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top values. Transforms are relative to the element's coordinates, not to those of the container.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer, but I've just found a solution :)

Comment: Your "solution" is in great need of improvement. First, setting Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top to zero before applying the transform is pointless, as the transform is relative to the element's origin. Second, setting rotation.CenterX to Width/2 and rotation.CenterY to Height/2 is not necessary, as you can simply set the transform center once in relative coordinates by a RenderTransformOrigin of (0.5, 0.5). Finally there is no need to create a new RotateTransform every time. Just set the Angle property of the existing one.